# Get TypeScript errors with tsc CLI without generating .js files

Tags: typescript

What command do you need to run to get the TypeScript errors in a `src` subfolder using the [tsc CLI](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html#handbook-content)?

This would be useful if, for example, you modified an exported `Type` that many modules imported and you wanted to see if that caused any errors without opening all the files manually.

Comment: what's the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--noEmit` flag to disable "emitting" files. Will still output compilation errors.

`tsc --noEmit`